# How to know which user you are tagging when both have same name?

Tags: discussion

Here I am facing a difficult situation on comment.

[I am not able to do simple database update using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585843/i-am-not-able-to-do-simple-database-update-using-codeigniter#34585914)

I want to tag the OP but tagging another community member who is taking part in discussion as both have same name.

How I can handle this situation ?

Comment: Tl;dr, the OP is always notified, so in your case don't mention anyone.